# Mariadb Return JSON for SELECT

Tags: json, mariadb, sequelize.js

I'm looking for a feature in Mariadb like

`SELECT ... FOR JSON` in SQL Server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server.

Currently I have code accessing the database via sequalize and I'm having major performance issues with large selects, I'm suspecting largely from turning the response into JSON.

Comment: MariaDB has good support for [JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/json-functions/) but there is not one for selecting as JSON. You might need to insert as JSON or have something in the middle which handles the conversion.

Comment: Thanks, I did find a lot of optimizations around other parts of code to get rid of most of the bottle neck. The query still takes ~7 seconds from a network perspective but its at least more manageable.